# How do I only have x-axis labels that specify when the year is changed in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, axis-labels

I've downloaded a couple of .csv files, and they look something like this, just a lot longer and the date continues until 2020-03-13.

```
        Date    Open    High     Low   Close Adj.Close     Volume
1 2015-03-13 2064.56 2064.56 2041.17 2053.40   2053.40 3498560000
2 2015-03-16 2055.35 2081.41 2055.35 2081.19   2081.19 3295600000
3 2015-03-17 2080.59 2080.59 2065.08 2074.28   2074.28 3221840000
4 2015-03-18 2072.84 2106.85 2061.23 2099.50   2099.50 4128210000
5 2015-03-19 2098.69 2098.69 2085.56 2089.27   2089.27 3305220000
6 2015-03-20 2090.32 2113.92 2090.32 2108.10   2108.10 5554120000
```

I've created a data frame that looks like this based on the data

```
        Date t        SandP          AMD
1          0 1  0.000000000  0.000000000
2 2015-03-16 2  0.013442909  0.003629768
3 2015-03-17 3 -0.003325698  0.003616640
4 2015-03-18 4  0.012085102 -0.007246409
5 2015-03-19 5 -0.004884489 -0.003642991
6 2015-03-20 6  0.008972382  0.021661497
```

I am trying to graph the SandP and AMD columns on the same axis, however I only want the axis labels to show each year (when each year changes). Therefore I would only want the 6 ticks on the axis (2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020).

If it helps, the .csv files were downloaded from Yahoo Finance data for S&P500.

This is my code up to now:

```
SPdata <- read.csv("^GSPC.csv")
AMDdata <- read.csv("AMD.csv")

head(SPdata)

R_t <- function(t){
  S=log(SPdata[t,6])-log(SPdata[t-1,6])
  return(S)
}
S_t <- function(t){
  S=log(AMDdata[t,6])-log(AMDdata[t-1,6])
  return(S)
}

comparedata <- data.frame(0,1,0,0)
names(comparedata)[1]<-"Date"
names(comparedata)[2]<-"t"
names(comparedata)[3]<-"SandP"
names(comparedata)[4]<-"AMD"


t<-2
while(t<1260){
  comparedata <-rbind(comparedata, list(AMDdata[t,1],t,R_t(t),S_t(t)))
  t=t+1
}

# install.packages("ggplot2")
library("ggplot2")

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=comparedata, aes(x=Date,y=SandP),color="red",group=1)+
  geom_line(data=comparedata, aes(x=Date,y=AMD), color="blue",group=1)+
  labs(x="Date",y="Returns")
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. To make it easier for us to help you, could you post the output of `dput(comparedata[seq_len(n), ])` wherein `n` is a row number such that the data includes at least 2 years? The example data you posted is neither easy to copy, nor does it span multiple years, which is needed to adress your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `scale_x_date` and set the argument `date_breaks` and `date_labels` (see the offficial documentation: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html)

Here, I recreate an example using the small portion of the data you provided:

```r
library(lubridate)
date <- seq(ymd("2015-03-16"), ymd("2020-03-13"), by = "day")
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 t = 1:1825,
                 SandP = rnorm(1825),
                 AMD = rnorm(1825))
```

Starting from this example,  I reshape the dataframe into a longer format using `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr`:

```r
library(tidyr)
DF <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(SandP, AMD), names_to = "indices", values_to = "values")

# A tibble: 3,650 x 4
   date           t indices  values
   <date>     <int> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 2015-03-16     1 SandP    0.566 
 2 2015-03-16     1 AMD     -0.185 
 3 2015-03-17     2 SandP   -1.59  
 4 2015-03-17     2 AMD      0.236 
 5 2015-03-18     3 SandP    1.11  
 6 2015-03-18     3 AMD     -1.52  
 7 2015-03-19     4 SandP   -1.02  
 8 2015-03-19     4 AMD      0.0833
 9 2015-03-20     5 SandP    2.78  
10 2015-03-20     5 AMD     -0.173 
# … with 3,640 more rows
```

Then, I plot both indices according to the date using `ggplot2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = date, y = values, color = indices))+
  geom_line()+
  labs(x="Date",y="Returns")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y")
```

[image]

Does it look what you are trying to achieve ?